# Who holds the license for Cadillacs & Dinosaurs?

Tags: cadillacs-and-dinosaurs, copyright

Who currently owns the *[Cadillacs & Dinosaurs/Xenozoic Tales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenozoic_Tales)* license? (Or, how can I find out who does?)

Comment: But who has the game rights???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since [Mark Schultz](http://www.deniskitchen.com/docs/bios/bio_mark_schultz.html), the creator of these tales, [is supposedly still alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Schultz_%28comics%29), I would think the rights still belong to him.  For TV shows, CBS  was involved, as well as Tyco for the toy distribution rights.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Even if he's not the rights holder at the moment, he'll probably have a good idea who is.

Answer (score 1):

The image below is from the first printing of the comic series; Xenozoic Tales. As you can see, the *individual copyright credit* for the panels found in the comics goes to artist Mark Schultz but the rights-holders for the Xenozoic Tales trademark (and presumably any ongoing use of the work) was Kitchen Sink Press, Inc.

[image]

According to the wikipedia article on [Kitchen Press](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitchen_Sink_Press), the company went bankrupt in 1999 and was resurrected under the heading of [Denis Kitchen Press Inc](http://deniskitchen.com/) in 2001. Since then, they've appear to have held (and asserted) the rights on a continuous basis.

You can find their address and contact details [here](http://www.deniskitchen.com/docs/new_contact.html).

Comment: *As you can see, the individual credit is for Mark Schultz but the rights-holders were Kitchen Sink Press, Inc.* No, what I see is that Schulz holds the copyright on the comic itself, but Kitchen Sink Press has trademarked its name. If Kitchen Sink Press held the rights to the actual comic (i.e., it was work-for-hire) that would read "Xenozoic Tales #14 © Kitchen Sink Press."

Comment: @Micah - If you're after the rights for sale, it's unlikely that the original author would negotiate when he has a pre-exiting (30+ year) arrangement with a publishing house.

Comment: I agree, but that wasn't the question. (Also, I'm not sure where you're pulling "50+ year" from; Kitchen Sink is only 44 years old!)

Comment: @Micah - The perils of typing from a mobile.